# Efficient casting of types for calculation

Tags: java, casting, prefuse

I'm having a prefuse-table structure, i.e., each row is represented by a tuple and you can access values via `table.get(rowNumber, columnName)` or via `tuple.get(columnName)` - whereas get will return an `Object` there are more specific methods if you know the return type, such as `getDouble()` or `getInt()`.

Besides numbers the table also stores times, which are available as `String`, i.e., `08:15` or `20:10`. In order to calculate the mean appropriate I have to use the distance between two times (e.g., `11:55` or to be more exact `715` in minutes).

So each number is assigned to an interval length, which is used as a weighting factor, i.e., `tuple.getDouble("sales") * 60 / Double.valueOf(interval)`. Furthermore, it is added up in a variable called `mean` of the type `Number` (I used it because of its flexibility to use several number types). So overall, the line looks like `mean = mean.doubleValue + tuple.getDouble("sales") * 60 / Double.valueOf(interval);`

But not all number columns are of type `double` and thus, I have the same line for int, float and long. They just look like `mean = mean.intValue + tuple.getInt("aColumn") * 60 / Integer.valueOf(interval)` and so on. Of course in my case I check which type a column is beforehand and I end up with four `if`s and four lines of calculation.

Now I was wondering is there an efficient way to typecast all parameters I need. I can evaluate the type of the column by simply using `Class type = column.getColumnType();`

I cannot think of a way to design it more efficiently (and better looking), because if I try to use `type.cast()` within a calculation I'm being told that

> the operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int

Is there any way to typecast such calculations dynamically (probably with different data structures, i.e., not using `Number`)? It isn't terrible what I have now as it is working, it's just that I'm not really satisfied and it's terrible to look at if another person would continue with this code.

Comment: `instanceof` can be helpful. You can test runtime type of the object

Comment: Well, my problem is not that I cannot find out the correct type, but rather that I'd like to have one line of code instead of 8 (4 `if`s and 4 calculations). :) E.g., `mean = (Number) (type.cast(mean) + type.cast(tuple.get("sales)) * 60 / type.cast(interval));`, but I'm afraid there is no solution to my liking :(

Comment: I don't think there is one but would like to hear others as well

Comment: So do I, but I thought it might be worth asking as this is a problem I faced on several occassions and I couldn't find a nice solution for it.

Comment: Could overloading help you ? multiply(Integer i1, int i2)  multiply(Double d1, double d2) ...

Comment: @Berger Overloading is a good idea in general, I'll look into it if I can find a way to make it work. The problem here is that `type.cast(object)` will return an `Object` regardless of the actual cast type (e.g., if type is `Double`).

Comment: @Berger how overloading will be useful here. Can you please detail ? Because as per my understanding, it will work only if OP has the correct type to pass. and if there is an Object version of overloaded methods available, ll be called. Please correct if needed

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there often is no concise and relegant way to perform computations with arbitrary `Number` instances, *without* casting them. One workaround that *may* be applicable in many cases is to simply perform all operations using `double` (as in `number.doubleValue()`), and cast the result only when it has to be written back into a column that is e.g. of type `Integer`. But note that, e.g. not all `long` values may be represented as `double` without losing precision.

Comment: Generally speaking, trying to overload different numeric types into one structure is basically fundamentally doomed to failure in Java.